# Display 3D spherical model on hemispherical display

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, 3d, three.js, webgl

I would like to project a 3D sphere in Three.js (like http://simia.net/wikiglobe/) onto a hemispherical dome display. I would like the surface of the sphere to appear on the surface of the hemispherical display (For my purposes it is ok if only half the sphere's surface is visible at once)

What sort of transformation could I to perform so that the surface of the sphere would display appropriately on the display?

Comment: You can find a lot about projections at http://paulbourke.net/geometry/transformationprojection/